# automatically add new files to installer

Tags: installation, installshield

I maintain several InstallShield projects and I frequently have to add new files to my installers, it's a bit tedious to open up a project + manually add/remove a file + check-in the updated project every time. I would like to simplify this process so that I could just place the new file in a particular folder which would be handled by the (automated) build of the installer project **without** having to open (modify) the project itself.

Let's assume that the new files are not .DLL's which must be registered on the target system (because InstallShield might have to perform COM extraction which makes it impossible (or very difficult) to automate the process of adding this type of file)

One possible solution would be to write a pre-build script which takes all files in a specific folder and puts them into foo.zip, the installer will deploy foo.zip which contains an arbitrary number of files, this can be accomplished with a Custom Action which calls 7zip with the appropriate command-line options.

Is there a more elegant solution to this problem ? (without zipping a folder & invoking 7zip)

Comment: Is it adding the files that are tedious or the fact that you have to work on installers at all that's tedious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic File Linking or Automation Interface.